# Is there a Debug Dashboard like Laravel Telescope for Django?

Tags: django

I need to monitor some request and queries like I do easy with Laravel Telescope, is there something like it for Django?

Answer (score 2):

The closed thing in Django probably is [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) for the python side.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created a package called [django-sonar](https://github.com/metalogico/django-sonar/). I couldn't find anything better in the django ecosystem so I've made it by myself.